# 3 Sat to 2 coloring

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, coloring, np-complete, satisfiability

If we have a set of elements and we can split them into different subsets. We can color the elements either red or blue. Check if there is a way to color the elements such that there is no subset that contains one color.

I want to prove this problem is NP-Complete using boolean SAT (i.e. I need to reduce SAT to this problem).

Any variation of the SAT problem is fine. E.g. 3 SAT.

Comment: Do you mean you have a particular, explicit, list of subsets that must not be monochrome?

Comment: Note that DNF-SAT is not NP-hard.

Comment: yes @HenningMakholm

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** For each-variable in a CNF-SAT problem have two elements in your set, representing $x$ and $\neg x$. Then emit the 2-element subset $\{x,\neg x\}$ to force them to have opposite colors.

Also have a special global element $0$. It can end up being either red or blue, but whatever it ends up being will encode "false" (and the other color will then be "true").

Can you now see how to encode a single clause as a subset-that-must-not-be-monochrome?

Comment: this is the trivial part, the rest is the difficult part. Thanks for the hint though

Comment: @Ysrninja:  What is "the rest" that is difficult here? Proving that the problem is actually in NP? That is trivial -- just guess a coloring and check that it meets the constraints.